# KeyError: "marketplace" while downloading "amazon_us_reviews" dataset - huggingface datasets

Tags: python, huggingface-transformers, huggingface, huggingface-datasets

I am trying to download the `amazon_us_reviews` dataset using the following code:

```
from datasets import load_dataset
dataset = load_dataset("amazon_us_reviews", "Toys_v1_00")
```

I am getting the following error:

````
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/datasets/builder.py in _prepare_split_single(self, gen_kwargs, fpath, file_format, max_shard_size, split_info, check_duplicate_keys, job_id)
   1692         )
-> 1693         self._beam_writers[split_name] = beam_writer
   1694 

11 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/datasets/features/features.py in encode_example(self, example)
   1850         ```
-> 1851         """
   1852         return copy.deepcopy(self)

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/datasets/features/features.py in encode_nested_example(schema, obj, level)
   1228     """Decode a nested example.
-> 1229     This is used since some features (in particular Audio and Image) have some logic during decoding.
   1230 

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/datasets/features/features.py in <dictcomp>(.0)
   1228     """Decode a nested example.
-> 1229     This is used since some features (in particular Audio and Image) have some logic during decoding.
   1230 

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/datasets/utils/py_utils.py in zip_dict(*dicts)
    321     def __get__(self, obj, objtype=None):
--> 322         return self.fget.__get__(None, objtype)()
    323 

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/datasets/utils/py_utils.py in <genexpr>(.0)
    321     def __get__(self, obj, objtype=None):
--> 322         return self.fget.__get__(None, objtype)()
    323 

KeyError: 'marketplace'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

DatasetGenerationError                    Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-25-341913a5da6a> in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 dataset = load_dataset("amazon_us_reviews", "Toys_v1_00")

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/datasets/load.py in load_dataset(path, name, data_dir, data_files, split, cache_dir, features, download_config, download_mode, verification_mode, ignore_verifications, keep_in_memory, save_infos, revision, token, use_auth_token, task, streaming, num_proc, storage_options, **config_kwargs)

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/datasets/builder.py in download_and_prepare(self, output_dir, download_config, download_mode, verification_mode, ignore_verifications, try_from_hf_gcs, dl_manager, base_path, use_auth_token, file_format, max_shard_size, num_proc, storage_options, **download_and_prepare_kwargs)
    952         with FileLock(lock_path) if is_local else contextlib.nullcontext():
    953             self.info.write_to_directory(self._output_dir, fs=self._fs)
--> 954 
    955     def _save_infos(self):
    956         is_local = not is_remote_filesystem(self._fs)

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/datasets/builder.py in _download_and_prepare(self, dl_manager, verification_mode, **prepare_splits_kwargs)

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/datasets/builder.py in _download_and_prepare(self, dl_manager, verification_mode, **prepare_split_kwargs)
   1047             in_memory=in_memory,
   1048         )
-> 1049         if run_post_process:
   1050             for resource_file_name in self._post_processing_resources(split).values():
   1051                 if os.sep in resource_file_name:

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/datasets/builder.py in _prepare_split(self, split_generator, check_duplicate_keys, file_format, num_proc, max_shard_size)
   1553 
   1554 class BeamBasedBuilder(DatasetBuilder):
-> 1555     """Beam based Builder."""
   1556 
   1557     # BeamBasedBuilder does not have dummy data for tests yet

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/datasets/builder.py in _prepare_split_single(self, gen_kwargs, fpath, file_format, max_shard_size, split_info, check_duplicate_keys, job_id)

DatasetGenerationError: An error occurred while generating the dataset
````

I tried with the `load_dataset_builder` it is showing the following features:

```
from datasets import load_dataset_builder
ds_builder = load_dataset_builder("amazon_us_reviews", "Toys_v1_00")
print(ds_builder.info.features)
```

Output:

```
{'marketplace': Value(dtype='string', id=None),
 'customer_id': Value(dtype='string', id=None),
 'review_id': Value(dtype='string', id=None),
 'product_id': Value(dtype='string', id=None),
 'product_parent': Value(dtype='string', id=None),
 'product_title': Value(dtype='string', id=None),
 'product_category': Value(dtype='string', id=None),
 'star_rating': Value(dtype='int32', id=None),
 'helpful_votes': Value(dtype='int32', id=None),
 'total_votes': Value(dtype='int32', id=None),
 'vine': ClassLabel(names=['N', 'Y'], id=None),
 'verified_purchase': ClassLabel(names=['N', 'Y'], id=None),
 'review_headline': Value(dtype='string', id=None),
 'review_body': Value(dtype='string', id=None),
 'review_date': Value(dtype='string', id=None)}
```

The `datasets` version used is `2.14.4`

Is this the correct way to download the dataset? Kindly advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntax is correct, I think the issue is on Amazon's side - even the publicly-facing root page which should contain a README is now throwing access denied: https://s3.amazonaws.com/amazon-reviews-pds/readme.html

Perhaps use a different dataset for now, there is also [amazon_reviews_multi](https://huggingface.co/datasets/amazon_reviews_multi).

**Update**:

> Amazon has decided to stop distributing this dataset.

[Refer here](https://github.com/huggingface/datasets/issues/6099#issuecomment-1671349110)